# Spring boot - welcome page

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot 1.2.7. Have added the welcome page as below:

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {

   // ....

   factory.addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(Context context) {
                    context.addWelcomeFile("/landingPage");                 
                }
            });
}
```

In WebMvc,

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController( "/" ).setViewName( "landingPage" );
        registry.setOrder( Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE );
        super.addViewControllers( registry );
    }
}
```

But, it is not working. Am i missing any config?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Maybe you forgot to add template engine, f.e. Thymeleaf?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring-boot why would you need to use TomcatContextCustomizer and  you have overridden the default configuration of spring-boot by extending from  WebMvcConfigurerAdapter this means the spring boot auto configuration will not work because it is now overridden by your MvcConfig  class. Hope this answer your question.